# How can a rotating cylinder produce lift?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, angular-momentum, lift

In the air, the velocity and angular momentum that causes a force against gravity is lift. How can a rotating cylinder make lift with angular momentum?

Comment: Look up the Magnus Effect. Plenty of questions here about it as well: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/171863/ for example

Comment: Ok , I know what is Magnus effect but if you can , explain this question .

Comment: If you *really* knew how the Magnus effect worked, you would already know the answer your question. I don't have time to answer it, I was merely providing you with information on where/what to look for. And just a hint, it's due to viscosity -- turns out almost *everything* in fluids works back to viscosity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [By what mechanism is lift produced on a rotating cylinder in an inviscid flow?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/171974/)

Comment: pictures say more than words: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23f1jvGUWJs